# How to use C language format specifiers in C#

Tags: c#, .net, format-specifiers

Consider this as my input:

```
number : 123
pattern: %5d

Output in C after string formatting : "  123"
```

**Note**: *White spaces are displayed in first two positions.*

To be exact, my input patterns will be in C language format and I'd like to get the functionality of those formats(result should be same as in C) in C#.

Comment: You'll have to parse the string (a regex might help for specific known formats) and re-format it yourself.

Comment: May I know the pattern which I have to specify ?

Comment: @ramkumar that's your job, to think up the regular-expressions that match each C string-format specifier :)

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19274/A-printf-implementation-in-C

Answer (score 4):

The correct C# syntax for that is:

```
string.Format("{0,5}", number)
```

It [pads the number by 5 positions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (spaces). You can use regex if you want to convert the one to the other.

Or with C# 6 string interpolation syntax:

```
$"{number,5}"
```

Comment: More information at [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Indeed. Added @Alex. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer @patrick. In my case, the input pattern will be in a C language format (i.e. like %3d, %f etc..). I'd like to get the same functionality (C language formatting) in C#.

Comment: That would require a parser to parse each and every C format specifier to C#. That is an endless job and too broad for SO I think. (And that was actually not your question as I read it)

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this behavior without using a pattern or Regex. Use the .NET framework [`string.PadLeft()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method instead:

```
int number = 123;
var result = number.ToString().PadLeft(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use custom numeric format strings. Which can be found here: [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

I would go with The "#" custom format specifier.